# Why does this cause an InvalidOperationException: Out of sync?

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

The goal of the following code is to have "hotkeys" (for lack of a better word). Such a hotkey is a checkbox that toggles multiple checkboxes.

I understand that Dictionaries throw an out of sync exception when you try to change a dictionary while looping over it. But the one I'm looping over is only being read from.

**I've found a solution, but am still interested in why this causes the exception.**

```
public class JointTypeSelectDisplay
{
    public Dictionary<JointType, bool> SelectedJoints;  
    private Dictionary<JointType, JointTypeListElement> _jointToggles;

    private void UpdateDisplay()
    {
        foreach (var joint in SelectedJoints)
        {
            _jointToggles[joint.Key].SetState(SelectedJoints[joint.Key]);
        }
    }
}

public class JointTypeListElement
{
    public Toggle JointToggle;

    public void SetState(bool active)
    {
        JointToggle.isOn = active;
    }
}
```

EDIT: stacktrace:

> InvalidOperationException: out of sync
>
> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2+Enumerator[Windows.Kinect.JointType,System.Boolean].VerifyState () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:912)
>
> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2+Enumerator[Windows.Kinect.JointType,System.Boolean].MoveNext () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:835)
>
> KinectFilterTesting.JointTypeSelectDisplay.UpdateDisplay () (at Assets/Scripts/Simon/JointTypeSelectDisplay.cs:146)
>
> KinectFilterTesting.JointTypeSelectDisplay.SetSelectedState (System.Collections.Generic.List'1 types, Boolean selected) (at Assets/Scripts/Simon/JointTypeSelectDisplay.cs:131)
>
> KinectFilterTesting.JointTypeSelectDisplay.SetRightArm (Boolean selected) (at Assets/Scripts/Simon/JointTypeSelectDisplay.cs:160)
>
> UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall'1[System.Boolean].Invoke (System.Object[] args) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:141)
>
> UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:574)
>
> UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:716)
>
> UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent'1[System.Boolean].Invoke (Boolean arg0) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent_1.cs:53)
>
> UnityEngine.UI.Toggle.Set (Boolean value, Boolean sendCallback) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Toggle.cs:167)
>
> UnityEngine.UI.Toggle.Set (Boolean value) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Toggle.cs:142)
>
> UnityEngine.UI.Toggle.set_isOn (Boolean value) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Toggle.cs:136)
>
> UnityEngine.UI.Toggle.InternalToggle () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Toggle.cs:199)
>
> UnityEngine.UI.Toggle.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Toggle.cs:210)
>
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:52)
>
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerClickHandler] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction'1 functor) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:269)
>
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()

Comment: Why use `SelectedJoints[joint.Key]` instead of `joint.Value`?

Comment: @juharr Not quite sure, must be a leftover from trying different solutions. Anyway, your suggestion is still throwing the out of sync exceptions.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that would fix the error, just curious.  Can you include the stack trace so we can see exactly where the exception is thrown?

Comment: @juharr I've added it. Lots of unity specific stuff in there though.

Comment: You have multiple threads accessing that dictionary? Tried the ConcurrentDictionary?

Comment: @Brannon ConcurrentDictionary is not available in unity, so I can't check. But if multiple threads *are* using the data, it's happening internally without my knowledge.

Comment: Can you provide the context of the call to `UpdateDisplay()`? And how `SelectedJoints` is updated? It looks like when you set one toggle to on, it triggers another event that change the content of SelectedJoints while the first call is still iterating through it.

Comment: @Kryptos That must be it. Setting `isOn` does indeed trigger an event. But I'm not sure of the internals of Unity. That's why my initial thought was that the event would be triggered *after* looping through `SelectedJoints`.

Answer (score 2):

The probability is that `SelectedJoints` is being modified on another thread. The easiest way to fix this is to make a copy of the keys and iterate over them:

```
private void UpdateDisplay()
{
    List<JointType> joints = new List<JointType>(SelectedJoints.Keys);

    foreach (JointType joint in joints)
    {
        if(_jointToggles.ContainsKey(joint) && SelectedJoints.ContainsKey(joint))
            _jointToggles[joint].SetState(SelectedJoints[joint]);
    }
}
```

Note that the if-condition is needed as your error strongly suggests that your collection is being modified while `UpdateDisplay` is being executed. Also this will not catch scenarios where an entry is added to `SelectedJoints` while `UpdateDisplay` is running so it might make sense to run `UpdateDisplay` more frequently if you're not already doing that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As I mentioned, I already had a solution, which is quite similar to yours (I loop over `SelectedJoints.Keys.ToArray()`). As for the cause, it's what Kryptos suggested in his comment.

Comment: Maybe you could update the states in the `LateUpdate()` method. I think this would prevent new events to be triggered during the same frame (this was a kind of trick used in previous Unity version. I don't know about the internals of the new UI system).